# PHP - Range of consecutive true array keys

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, filtering

I have the following dataset:

```
$slots = [
  "00:00" => true
  "00:15" => true
  "00:30" => true
  "00:45" => true
  "01:00" => false
  "01:15" => false
  "01:30" => false
  "01:45" => false
  "02:00" => true
  "02:15" => false
  "02:30" => false
  "02:45" => false
  "03:00" => true
  "03:15" => true
  "03:30" => true
  "03:45" => false
  "04:00" => false
  "04:15" => false
  "04:30" => false
  "04:45" => false
  "05:00" => false
  "05:15" => false
  "05:30" => false
  "05:45" => false
  "06:00" => false
  "06:15" => false
  "06:30" => false
  "06:45" => false,
  .........
];
```

I need to come up with an efficient solution to get intervals for when the values is true. Like in the above dataset i need to generate something like this:

```
$trueSlots = ['00:00-00:45', '02:00-02:00', '03:00-03:30'];
```

I'm having a bad day and seem to over-complicate it.

**edit:**
What can work too is the following return format:

```
$trueSlots = [
  '00:00' => '00:45',
  '02:00' => '02:00',
  '03:00' => '03:30',
];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over your list, saving the slot time when the status changes from `false` to `true`, and pushing a new entry into the result array when the status changes from `true` to `false`, and also at the end if the last status was true. Note I've made each entry in the output an array of start and finish times, it's easy enough to change that into whatever format you desire:

```
$result = [];
$last = false;
foreach ($slots as $slot => $taken) {
    if ($taken && !$last) $start = $slot;
    if ($last && !$taken) $result[] = [$start, $end];  // or "$start-$end";
    $last = $taken;
    $end = $slot;
}
// did we finish on a taken slot?
if ($last) $result[] = [$start, $end];  // or "$start-$end";
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 00:00
            [1] => 00:45
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 02:00
            [1] => 02:00
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 03:00
            [1] => 03:30
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/4diGn)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: Collect all the consecutive true slots in arrays first, then loop over those again to take only the first and last element, resp. duplicate the first element, if there is only one.

```
$result = [];
$i = 0;

foreach($slots as $slot => $value) {
  if(!$value) {
    ++$i;
  }
  else {
    $result[$i][] = $slot;
  }
}
```

This will get you the following result,

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '00:00' (length=5)
      1 => string '00:15' (length=5)
      2 => string '00:30' (length=5)
      3 => string '00:45' (length=5)
  4 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '02:00' (length=5)
  7 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '03:00' (length=5)
      1 => string '03:15' (length=5)
      2 => string '03:30' (length=5)
```

The keys have “holes” now, because I simply increased `$i` for every `false` slot, the following line fixes that:

```
$result = array_values($result);
```

And now, all of those sub-arrays have to be condensed to just the first and last item, resp. have the first one duplicated, if there is only one:

```
foreach($result as $key => $value) {
  $c = count($value);
  if($c == 1) {
    $result[$key][] = $result[$key][0];
  }
  else {
    $result[$key] = [$result[$key][0], $result[$key][$c-1]];
  }
}
```

End result:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '00:00' (length=5)
      1 => string '00:45' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '02:00' (length=5)
      1 => string '02:00' (length=5)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '03:00' (length=5)
      1 => string '03:30' (length=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up with is the following (using Laravel's Collections):

```
$slots = [
  "00:00" => false,
  "00:15" => true,
  "00:30" => true,
  "00:45" => true,
  "01:00" => false,
  "01:15" => false,
  "01:30" => false,
  "01:45" => false,
  "02:00" => true,
  "02:15" => false,
  "02:30" => false,
  "02:45" => false,
  "03:00" => true,
  "03:15" => true,
  "03:30" => true,
  "03:45" => false,
  "04:00" => false,
  "04:15" => false,
  "04:30" => false,
  "04:45" => false,
  "05:00" => false,
  "05:15" => false,
  "05:30" => false,
  "05:45" => false,
  "06:00" => false,
  "06:15" => false,
  "06:30" => false,
  "06:45" => false,
];

$slots = collect($slots);
$hasTrue = $slots->filter(fn($t) => $t === true)->count();

$intervals = [];

while($hasTrue > 0) {
 $int = $slots->takeUntil(fn($item) => $item === false);
  if($int->count() > 0) {
    $intervals[$int->keys()->first()] = $int->keys()->last();
    foreach($int as $key => $truth) {
     $slots->pull($key);
    }
  } else {
    $slots->shift();
  }
  
  $hasTrue = $slots->filter(fn($t) => $t === true)->count();
}

print_r($intervals);
=> [
     "00:15" => "00:45",
     "02:00" => "02:00",
     "03:00" => "03:30",
   ]
```

I'm sure the following above work, thanks for those, but until i got an answer i decided to give Collections a try too.